# hide form using javascript, simple error

Tags: javascript

I'm beginner with Javascript. I've tried to hide a form with no luck.

Where is the error ?

http://jsfiddle.net/6EWCe/5/

```
<div id="form1">    
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
</div>

<div id="form2">    
<form>
First name:2 <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name:2 <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="hideform()">Close</a>


function hideform() {
    document.getElementById('form2').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Depending on what browser you use to test your JS, use the console, as it will tell you both *what* your error is and *where* it is. That should help you in the future.

http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: hideform is not defined

...is your error.

You need to specify that you want your JavaScript to load in the `body` of your JSFiddle demo using the options in the sidebar:

[image: Example]

[Fixed JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6EWCe/6/).